# doPost(e) google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working with Google Script and I have a problem with `doPost(e)`, every time I send a POST request to the script I keep getting undefined the variable e

My code:

```
function doPost(e){
  var company = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)['meta']['company_id'];
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1lEp4Ul0D3eGsIEbjS6rFhjVVVjH6v5ZJvxRfGr5WLWQ');
  var ss = s.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  var token = 'hidden secret token';
  // get previous and current data from post
  var previous = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)['previous'];
  //set the previous stage id to current object
  current['previous_stage_id'] = previous['stage_id'];}
```

the post responses are all raw body.

Comment: How is the function "doPost" getting called?

Comment: its called on a external trigger.

Comment: You'll probably need to post the code that makes the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

If this information is supposed to cause something to happen on the  script side of things you need to add a

```
google.script.run.functionName(responseValues)
```

to the HTML. If the HTML needs to get values back add a handler.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doSomething).functionName()
```

The doSomething is JS on the page and the functionName is a google script function.